# Is it possible to change how entity reference field is displayed?

Tags: forms, entities, 8

I have an entity that I has a taxonomy reference in it.  it currently looks like this

[image]

and I want this

[image]

Is this one of the options in display options array?  Or is it something different?  How do I change this?

This is my code

```
$fields['category'] = BaseFieldDefinition::create('entity_reference')
      ->setLabel(t('Category'))
      ->setDescription(t('Section this poll is to appear on'))
      ->setSetting('target_type', 'taxonomy_term')
      ->setTranslatable(TRUE)
            ->setDefaultValueCallback('Drupal\poll\Entity\Poll::getMain')
      ->setDisplayOptions('form', array(
        'type' => 'entity_reference_autocomplete',
        'weight' => -10,
        'settings' => array(
          'match_operator' => 'CONTAINS',
          'size' => '60',
          'autocomplete_type' => 'tags',
          'placeholder' => '',
        ),
      ))
      ->setDisplayConfigurable('form', TRUE)
            ->setRequired(FALSE);
```

Comment: Is it that you want the field widget to *look* different, or do you want it to behave as a multiple-value field instead of a single-value field?

Comment: I would like both.  more so the multiple value field

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You just need to set the cardinality of the field.

```
->setCardinality(BaseFieldDefinition::CARDINALITY_UNLIMITED)
```

Note that you need to re-install (to be safe, uninstall *before* making the change) or write an update function to convert the database structure if you make this change.

Comment: This worked almost perfectly. I did this, uninstalled and reinstalled the module, but now i have a problem with view.  I was using views contextual filters to change which one is displayed on different pages.  In order to do that i needed to add a relationship.  now it wont let me at the relationship, and my category field is not available for the contextual filter.  why is that?

Comment: Yes, that's a known missing feature/bug, the automated views data generation doesn't work for multi-value base fields. See https://www.drupal.org/node/2477899. You'll either need to try the patches there but I have no idea in what state they are or define the views data yourself for now. Create a similar configurable field (that works), then dump the generated views data and adjust it.